# c# can't get attributes out of xml

Tags: c#, xml, url, windows-phone, linq-to-xml

I have a problem where im trying to get the values from the attributes of a xml file from a url.

xml: http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=x-men

code:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += RequestCompleted;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new     Uri("http://thegamesdb.net/api/GetGamesList.php?name=x-men"));
    }

    private void RequestCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            var feedXml = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

            var gameData = feedXml.Root.Elements("Game").Select(x => new GetGamesList
              {
// ERROR VALUES ARE NULL
                  ID = (int)x.Attribute("id"), 
                  GameTitle = (string)x.Attribute("GameTitle"),
                  ReleaseDate = (string)x.Attribute("ReleaseDate"),
                  Platform = (string)x.Attribute("Platform")
              })
              .ToList();
        }
    }

public class GetGamesList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string GameTitle { get; set; }
    public string ReleaseDate { get; set; }
    public string Platform { get; set; }
}
```

I hope there is someone that can help me, thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to get just one element?

Comment: Yes right now im just trying to get one of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id, GameTitle, ReleaseDate` and `Platform` are all elements under `Game`, viz:

```
  ID = int.Parse(x.Element("id")), 
  GameTitle = (string)x.Element("GameTitle"),
  ReleaseDate = (string)x.Element("ReleaseDate"),
  Platform = (string)x.Element("Platform")
```

You'll also need to parse the int.

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks. But i thought <Game> was a "Element" and <id> was a "Attribute" ?,

Comment: Attributes in xml are on the element, in quotes, e.g. your code would parse xml like this : `<Game id="665" GameTitle="X-Men" ReleaseDate="1993" Platform="Sega Genesis" />`

Comment: Thanks, but when is it a attribute in a xml file?

Answer (score 0):

You need `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Select`. Try this in place of Select:

```
.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Attribute("id") == "665")
```

Just replace the `665` portion with the id# you want.

EDIT: in looking at StuartLC's answer and the provided xml file. I overlooked the simple design that you used. The data that you are trying to get are indeed elements, not attributes. So you would need to replace the `Attribute` call to `Element` like so:

```
.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Element("id") == "665")
```

On a side note, the return value of `Elements` is an `IEnumerable<XElement>` which allows you to iterate over the values within it.

EDIT: This will return the `XElement` containing the desired data. At this point, you can use StuartLC's answer to transfer the data into your class.